# Maximum matching = Minimum odd vertex cover

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, duality-theorems, matching-theory, analysis-of-algorithms

Definition:
A set $C⊆V$ and a collection of subsets $_1,…,_⊆V$ is an odd vertex cover if for every edge  either $∩≠∅$ or $ ⊆ B_i$  for some .

The cost of the odd vertex cover is defined to be:
$|C| + \sum_{i=1}^{k} \lfloor{\frac{|B_i|}{2}}\rfloor$

Without loss of generality, we may assume that all the sets $B_i$ are of odd size, hence the name, and that C and $B_1,…,B_k$ are disjoint.

Theorem: In any graph, the size of the maximum matching is equal to the cost of the minimum odd vertex cover.

How can I prove it? I tried to use Edmond's algorithm for finding maximum match. Then to take one side of these edges as $C$ and the blossoms as $B_i$'s. I don't have a formal proof for that though.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Gallai-Edmonds decomposition?

Comment: No, this question was asked in a course I'm taking and the lecturer suggested the method I tried above